# IronPython implementing interface Properties

Tags: c#, properties, ironpython

i am implementing an interface defined in C# in ironPython, but cannot make
property implementation work:

C#

```
interface IInterface
 {
  Dictionary<string, element> Elements { get; }
 }
```

Python:

```
class Implementor(IInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = Dictionary[str, element]()

    def get_Elements(self):
        return self.elements
```

When calling to get_Elements, i get the following exception:

> Expected property for Elements, but found Dictionary[str, element]

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `def Implementor()` you're defining a method, not a class.
The correct code is `class Implementor()`:

```
class Implementor(IInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = Dictionary[str, element]()

    def get_Elements(self):
        return self.elements
```

this code works fine in my tests (I fetched a Implementor instance variable from the python scope into C# and the property works fine).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing mistake in this example, but the problem persists

Comment: @user1275011: the code works fine in my tests, so probably you are doing something different from me. Can you post more code (possibly a small but complete example reproducing the issue)?